# How do I parse every html file in a directory for images?

Tags: python, image, jpeg, beautifulsoup

I have a directory full of html files, each of which has a clinical image of a psoriasis patient in it.  I want to open each file, find the image, and save it in the same directory.

```
import os, os.path
import Image
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

path = 'C:\Users\gokalraina\Desktop\derm images'

for root, dirs, files in path:
    for f in files:
        soup = bs(f)
        for image in soup.findAll("img"):
            print "Image: %(src)s" % image
            im = Image.open(image)
            im.save(path+image["src"], "JPEG")
```

I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\gokalraina\Desktop\modfile.py", line 7, in <module>
     for root, dirs, files in path:
 ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Even after googling the error, I have no clue what is wrong or if I am doing this correctly.  Please keep in mind that I am new to python.

EDIT:  After making the suggested changes to the program, I am still getting an error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gokalraina\Desktop\modfile.py", line 25, in <module>
    im = Image.open(image)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1956, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

This is the revised code (thanks to nightcracker)

```
 import os, os.path
 import Image
 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

 path = 'C:\Users\gokalraina\Desktop\derm images'

 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
       soup = bs(open(os.path.join(root, f)).read())
       for image in soup.findAll("img"):
          print "Image: %(src)s" % image
          im = Image.open(image)
          im.save(path+image["src"], "JPEG")
```

Comment: Is `modfile.py` the source you posted? Line 7 seems to be a blank line, so I guess not.  You'll need to add `modfile.py` to your post.

Comment: Yes, modfile.py is the code posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
for root, dirs, files in path:
```

to

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
```

Also note that `files` are file **names**, not objects, so this would be your fixed code:

```
import os, os.path
import Image
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

path = 'C:\Users\gokalraina\Desktop\derm images'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        soup = bs(open(os.path.join(root, f)).read())
        for image in soup.findAll("img"):
            print "Image: %(src)s" % image
            im = Image.open(image)
            im.save(path+image["src"], "JPEG")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I changed that line of code in the program, but it still does not work as intended - there is no output on the console, nor any new files in the directory.  Is there something else that is done incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a list of something meaningful using `os.walk(path):` providing a String is a single thing, it is expecting a list of things.

The idiomatic way of walking a file system is to use [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html)

`for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):`

Answer (score 1):

```
for root, dirs, files in path:
```

`path` here is a string.  Each element is only a single character, and you can't unpack a single character into three variables. Hence the error message: you need more than one value to unpack.

You probably want:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
```